# How to refresh an AlertDialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

Currently, I have an `AlertDialog` with an `IconButton`. The user can click on the IconButton, I have two colors for each click. The problem is that I need to close the AlertDialog and reopen to see the state change of the color icon. I want to change the IconButton color immediately when the user clicks it.

Here is the code:

```
bool pressphone = false;
//....
new IconButton(
   icon: new Icon(Icons.phone),
   color: pressphone ? Colors.grey : Colors.green,
   onPressed: () => setState(() => pressphone = !pressphone),
),
```

Answer (score 463):

Use StatefulBuilder to use setState inside Dialog and update Widgets only inside of it.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: this is the right answer, I never thought you could 'subClass\subOverload' [setState]
live saviour

Comment: Not working for me either. Is there anyone who can explain why it is not working for some people?

Comment: I'm on Dart 2.8.1 and Flutter 1.19.0-0.0.pre, It's workin g as expecte in WEB, Thanks :)

Comment: @MutluSimsek It doesnt work when you trying to setState a variable that is declared outside of StatefulBuilder/StatefulWidget

Comment: Thanks. It's working for me. But if I add any child in a stateful builder from outside separate method it's not working. Then if I add the child directly inside the stateful builder it works. Changing the variable inside the stateful builder works. If it's outside the stateful builder then its not working.

Comment: This solution does not work in "content" attribute, only works in actions. @malibayram91 malibayram91 do you have any suggestion? Please share. Thanks.

Comment: I had to add `StatefulBuilder` between `showDialog` and `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 96):

Use a `StatefulBuilder` in the `content` section of the AlertDialog. Even the [StatefulBuilder docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) actually have an example with a dialog.

What it does is provide you with a new *context*, and *setState* function to rebuild when needed.

The sample code:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {

    int selectedRadio = 0; // Declare your variable outside the builder
    
    return AlertDialog( 
      content: StatefulBuilder(  // You need this, notice the parameters below:
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Column(  // Then, the content of your dialog.
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
              return Radio<int>(
                value: index,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                onChanged: (int value) {
                  // Whenever you need, call setState on your variable
                  setState(() => selectedRadio = value);
                },
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

And as I mentioned, this is what is said on the [showDialog docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html):

> [...] The widget returned by the builder does not share a context with the location
> that showDialog is originally called from. **Use a StatefulBuilder or a
> custom StatefulWidget if the dialog needs to update dynamically**.

Comment: Perfect! Was stuck on this for a long while!

Comment: Thank you for your code, and a reminder as in your code, variable must bu given outside from builder methot or you can spend your ten minutes why is the heck is that not working :D and answer is, if your StatefulBuilder widget, builder method recall, you are simply creating same state. Example (context, setState){bool isLoading=true;} => for this code, isloading always become true :D Again thank u, again.

Answer (score 87):

This is because you need to put your `AlertDialog` in its own `StatefulWidget` and move all state manipulation logic on the color there.

Update:

[image]

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Open Dialog'),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return MyDialog();
            });
      },
    )));
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => new _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  Color _c = Colors.redAccent;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
        color: _c,
        height: 20.0,
        width: 20.0,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
            child: Text('Switch'),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _c == Colors.redAccent
                      ? _c = Colors.blueAccent
                      : _c = Colors.redAccent;
                }))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you , I tried to create an other stful widget class but when I press the button to call my widet, I have nothing. Normaly when I call my alertdialog stfull widget It return this @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      content: new  Container ....

Comment: I'm trying to extend this to change the enabled/disabled state of the "ok" action button for a dialog.  But I'm not having any success yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the best way to do!

Comment: Perfect solution, for creating a stateful AlertDialog. Should have been the accepted answer, as this provides more options for code refactoring instead of nested blocks of code.
Thank you for the clean answer. 50+

Comment: very useful, thnak you

Comment: What if in Home there is a list and you have to refresh it on Dialog close ?

Comment: this answer is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 43):

First you need to use `StatefulBuilder`. Then i am setting `_setState` variable, which even could be used outside `StatefulBuilder`, to set new state.

```
StateSetter _setState;
String _demoText = "test";

showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {

    return AlertDialog( 
      content: StatefulBuilder(  // You need this, notice the parameters below:
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          _setState = setState;
          return Text(_demoText);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

_setState is used same way as setState method. For example like this:

```
_setState(() {
    _demoText = "new test text";
});
```

Comment: This work perfect for me, this is the only way that I found to be able to update the content of dialog from outside the dialog code.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me too

Comment: how to initialize the _setState variable

Comment: Perfect.. only way I found to update the variable outside the dialog. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

If you're separating your data from the UI via View Models and using the `Provider` package with `ChangeNotifier`, you'll need to include your current model like so within the widget calling the dialog:

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (dialog) {
              return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                  value: context.read<ViewModel>(),
                child: CustomStatefulDialogWidget(),
              );
            },
```

Note that there may be a cleaner way to do this but this worked for me.

Additional info regarding `Provider`: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: Thank a lot, this exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thx for the idea. I use Consumer in my case and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
        return Container(
          height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
          child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              heightOfModalBottomSheet += 10;
            });
          }),
        );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is best practice, but I solved the issue of updating both the dialog state and the content state by wrapping the setState functions, after using the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57240941/15011055) to add state to the dialog:

```dart
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, newSetState) { // Create a "new" state variable
          return AlertDialog(
            content: DropdownButton(
              value: listItem.type,
              items: allItems
              onChanged: (value) {
                newSetState(() {
                  setState(() {
                   // HERE SET THE STATE TWICE
                   // Once with the "new" state, once with the "old"
                  });
                });
              })
            ),
          );
        }
      );
    }
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use `StatefullBuilder` but the problem is that when you use this widget you cant change the state of the base screen! Prefer to navigate to a new screen in order to use `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

***I was stuck with this issue.You have to Change the name of setState to any Other name and pass this set state to all sub functions.
This will update your Dialog ui on time.***

```
 return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setStateSB) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Select Circle To Sync Data!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          content: Column(
              children: [
            Text("Select Division!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: sync_DivisionName_firstValue,
                          items: _DivisionName_list.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setStateSB(() {
                              sync_DivisionName_firstValue = newValue!;

                              if(sync_DivisionName_firstValue !="Select Division Name"){

                                print("sync_DivisionName_firstValue$sync_DivisionName_firstValue");
                                _getDistrictName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,setStateSB);
                              }else{
                                refreashDivisionName(setStateSB);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
            Text("Select District!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: sync_DistrictName_firstValue,
                          items: _DistrictName_list.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setStateSB(() {
                              sync_DistrictName_firstValue = newValue!;

                              if(sync_DivisionName_firstValue != "Select Division Name" && sync_DistrictName_firstValue != "Select District Name"){
                                print("sync_DistrictName_firstValue$sync_DistrictName_firstValue");

                                _getTehsilName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue,setStateSB);
                              }else{
                                refreashDistrictName(setStateSB);
                              }




                            });
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
            Text("Select Tehsil!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: sync_TehsilName_firstValue,
                          items: _TehsilName_list.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setStateSB(() {
                              sync_TehsilName_firstValue = newValue!;

                              if(sync_DivisionName_firstValue != "Select Division Name" && sync_DistrictName_firstValue != "Select District Name"  && sync_TehsilName_firstValue != "Select Tehsil Name"){
                                print("sync_TehsilName_firstValue$sync_TehsilName_firstValue");

                                _getRatingAreaName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue,sync_TehsilName_firstValue,setStateSB);
                              }else{
                                refreashTehsilName(setStateSB);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
                Text("Select Rating Area Name!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue,
                          items: _RatingAreaName_list.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setStateSB(() {
                              sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue = newValue!;

                              if(sync_DivisionName_firstValue != "Select Division Name" && sync_DistrictName_firstValue != "Select District Name"  && sync_TehsilName_firstValue != "Select Tehsil Name" && sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue != "Select Rating Area Name"){
                                print("sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue$sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue");

                                _getWardCircleName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue,sync_TehsilName_firstValue,sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue,setStateSB);
                              }else{
                                refreashWardCircleName(setStateSB);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
                Text("Select Ward Circle Name!" ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: sync_circle_name_firstValue,
                          items: _circle_name_list.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setStateSB(() {
                              sync_circle_name_firstValue = newValue!;
                              print("sync_circle_name_firstValue$sync_circle_name_firstValue");

                              // if(sync_circle_name_firstValue != "Select Ward Circle Name"){
                              //
                              //   _getWardCircleName(sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue);
                              // }else{
                              //
                              // }
                            });
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
          ]),
          backgroundColor:Color(0xFFEC9F46),
          actions: [
            okButton,SyncButton
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

**One of the Inner Funciton is like this.**

```
 Future<void> refreashDivisionName( StateSetter setInnerState) async {
    final List<String> _division_name = await getDivisionNameList();
    final List<String> _district_name_list = await getDistrictName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue);
    final List<String> _tehsil_name_list = await getTehsilName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue);
    final List<String> _rating_area_name_list = await getRatingAreaName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue,sync_TehsilName_firstValue);
    final List<String> _ward_circle_name_list = await getWardCircleName(sync_DivisionName_firstValue,sync_DistrictName_firstValue,sync_TehsilName_firstValue,sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue);


    setInnerState(() {
      _division_name.insert(0, "Select Division Name");
      _DivisionName_list = _division_name;
      sync_DivisionName_firstValue = _DivisionName_list[0];

      _district_name_list.insert(0, "Select District Name");
      _DistrictName_list = _district_name_list;
      sync_DistrictName_firstValue = _DistrictName_list[0];

      _tehsil_name_list.insert(0, "Select Tehsil Name");
      _TehsilName_list = _tehsil_name_list;
      sync_TehsilName_firstValue = _TehsilName_list[0];

      _rating_area_name_list.insert(0, "Select Rating Area Name");
      _RatingAreaName_list = _rating_area_name_list;
      sync_RatingAreaName_firstValue = _RatingAreaName_list[0];

      _ward_circle_name_list.insert(0, "Select Ward Circle Name");
      _circle_name_list = _ward_circle_name_list;
      sync_circle_name_firstValue = _circle_name_list[0];
    });
  }
```

***I hope you under Stand.***

Answer (score -1):

base on Andris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129750/5078054).

when dialog share the same state with parent widget, you can override parent widget's method setState to invoke StatefulBuilder's setState, so you don't need to call setState twice.

```
StateSetter? _setState;

Dialog dialog = showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {

    return AlertDialog( 
      content: StatefulBuilder(  // You need this, notice the parameters below:
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          _setState = setState;
          return Text(_demoText);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);

// set the function to null when dialo is dismiss.
dialogFuture.whenComplete(() => {_stateSetter = null});

@override
void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
   // invoke dialog setState to refresh dialog content when need
   _stateSetter?.call(fn);
   super.setState(fn);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently to retrieve the value of Dialog I use

```
showDialog().then((val){
setState (() {}); 
print (val);
});
```

Example
1st screen

```
    onPressed: () { 
    showDialog(
       context: context,
       barrierDismissible: false,
       builder: (context) {
         return AddDespesa();
       }).then((val) {
         setState(() {});
         print(val);
        }
    );
   }
```

2nd screen

```
AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Sucesso!"),
    content: Text("Gasto resgristrado com sucesso"),
    actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
         Navigator.pop(context, true);
      },
     ),
   ],
 );
```

Will be printed true,

Comment: This does not really change the state of the dialog, because the dialog has its own state and using the conventional setState is really not going to solve anything.