# setState is not working with DropDown Button in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm calculating total on the base of quantity when I select quantity from dropdown it gets changed but total amount `Textformfield` remain same and when I debug the code I get updated amount in `setState` method but does not reflect on the UI and I'm also updating total from another method in that method it is working.

```
 class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {


  List _quantity = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownQuantity;

  String _currentQuantity;
  String _productprice;
  double _taxrateamt;
  double _taxper = 0.0;
  String _producttotal;
  int _productqty;
  double _discount = 3.0;
  String _productname;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownQuantity() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = new List();
    for (String city in _quantity) {
      items.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
          value: city,
          child: new Text(
            city,
            style:
                TextStyle(color: MyColors.colorPrimary, fontFamily: 'semibold'),
          )));
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _dropDownQuantity = getDropDownQuantity();
    _currentQuantity = _dropDownQuantity[0].value;
  }

  Container rateAndTotal( String value) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'medium', color: MyColors.colorPrimaryDark),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    enabled: false,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    initialValue: '${value}',
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: '$value'),),),),],),],),);}

  Container quantity() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex:1,
                child: Container(
                     child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        value: _currentQuantity,
                        items: _dropDownQuantity,
                        onChanged: changedDropDownQuantity,),)),),],),],),);}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        MediaQueryData queryData;
        queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
        double width = queryData.size.width;
        double height = queryData.size.height;

        return new Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[200]),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(height * 0.020),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  quantity(),
                  rateAndTotal( '${_productprice}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }

  void changedDropDownQuantity(String selected_quantity) {
    setState(() {
      _currentQuantity = selected_quantity;
      // _producttotal=getProductTotal(_productprice,_currentQuantity);
    });

    setState(() {
      _producttotal=getProductTotal(_productprice,_currentQuantity);
    });

  }

  String getProductTotal(String productprice, String _currentQuantity) {
    try {

      double sprice = 0.0;
      double total = double.parse(productprice);
      double taxrate = _taxrateamt;
      double qty = double.parse(_currentQuantity);

      return _producttotal =
          (((total + taxrate + sprice) - _discount) * qty).toString();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('PRODUCT TOTAl EXC.:--${e}');

      return _producttotal = productprice;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, replace the below line in your TextFormField:

```
initialValue: '$value',
```

with:

```
controller: TextEditingController(text: value),
```

or better yet:

```
// Define a controller in the State
class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: value);

  ...
  // Then bind that controller to your TextFormField, replacing initialValue
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,

  ...

  // Then change the .text property of that controller when you want it to update
  setState(() => _controller.text = value);
```

`initialValue` is only used to set what the very first value of the `TextFormField` will be when the `State` is first initialised, and `State` is preserved through rebuilds so overriding it will never cause the text to change.

Overriding the `TextEditingController` completely each time or defining a `TextEditingController` and changing the `.text` property will properly pass the change to the `State` of the field and update your value.

Answer (score 0):

Another case; if you use dropdownbutton on pop-up, you need to use StatefulBuilder. Here is the reference; [How to refresh an AlertDialog in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-an-alertdialog-in-flutter)