# Flutter not updating DropdownButton placed within a dialog when item is selected

Tags: flutter

I have an alertDialog containing a DropdownButton widget. Whenever I click on an option within the dropDown I want it to display the selected value. I have listed the code below along with 2 screenshots.

I believe this may be an issue with how flutter builds widget because when I placed the DropdownButton widget outside of the dialog it worked, however placing it within an alertDialog causes it to fail. I also noticed that if I clicked on an option in the DropdownButton and then exited and clicked on the dialog again the selected item would change. However, I want the selected value to change without the user having to tap out of the dialog and then back in.

[image]

^

The above image is the dialog when a user first clicks on it. At first the only selected item is "I'm not able to help". This value should change whenever a user clicks on the DropdownMenu widget and selects a different option such as "other".

[image]

^

These are the various options a user can click on within the dropdown menu. When a user clicks on it, the menu should update accordingly.

**CODE:**

*Please note that I have defined _chosenValue as a global variable outside of the build function.*

```
void _showDecline() {

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {

          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Decline Appointment Request"),
            content: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Please select an option for why you declined."),
                  new DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _chosenValue,
                    underline: Container(),
                    items: <String>['I\'m not able to help', 'Unclear description', 'Not available at set date and time', 'Other'].map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                     onChanged: (String value) {
                       setState(() {
                        _chosenValue = value;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {},
                },
              ),
              
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh an AlertDialog in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-an-alertdialog-in-flutter)

Comment: No, I have a setState() operation in my code already and the dialog is also placed within a stateful widget.

Comment: So you tried it and it did not work? Post your best try using that link and we will see what's wrong.

Comment: The answers below all worked.

Comment: Well, big surpise, they all tell you the same that my link 12 hours ago told you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

setState will only update current StatefulWidget's Widget Build function.

You should use StatefulBuilder inside showDialog.

For your case just add StatefulBuilder as a parent of your DropDown widget, and use StateSetter when you want to update the StatefulBuilder's children.
It will only update the widget tree defined under StateFulBuilder builder function.

---

See the full code including **stateFulBuilder** at DartPad code  [StateFulBuilderDartPad](https://dartpad.dev/7a5a64dbe4061b66179a55d765075b88).

For more information on StatefulBuilder head over to [StateFulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) documentation page.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote your own answer, instead of voting for the duplicate?

Comment: I didn't get that duplicate question you mention in comment ,so i write my answer

Comment: i tried to explain the things, instead of just giving the code only....

Answer (score 13):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _chosenValue;

  void _showDecline() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Decline Appointment Request"),
              content:
                  Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                new Text("Please select an option for why you declined."),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: Text('Select one option'),
                      value: _chosenValue,
                      underline: Container(),
                      items: <String>[
                        'I\'m not able to help',
                        'Unclear description',
                        'Not available at set date and time',
                        'Other'
                      ].map((String value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(
                            value,
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _chosenValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )),
              ]),
              actions: <Widget>[
                // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: FlatButton(child: Text('Click'), onPressed: _showDecline),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: above my answer i solved error RIGHT OVERFLOWED BY 68 PIXELS .

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote your own answer, instead of voting for the duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

Just check out the below example you have to use the statefulBuilder to change the state.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _chosenValue;
 
  void _showDecline() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
            return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Decline Appointment Request"),
            content: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Please select an option for why you declined."),
                  new DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text('Select one option'),
                    value: _chosenValue,
                    underline: Container(),
                    items: <String>[
                      'I\'m not able to help',
                      'Unclear description',
                      'Not available at set date and time',
                      'Other'
                    ].map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(
                          value,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _chosenValue = value;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
          },
                  
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
              child: Container(
          child: FlatButton(child: Text('Click'), onPressed: _showDecline),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

***Try This ......***

**implement the alert on separate dart file and call it. that worked for me.**

***Important*** -  there was used following dropdown plugin because that ui better for me...
Link - [dropdown_button2: ^1.2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

**on main page call to the alert as follows.**

```
import 'package:crmapp/pages/payment_history/payment_history_search_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PaymentHistoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentHistoryScreenState createState() => _PaymentHistoryScreenState();
}

class _PaymentHistoryScreenState extends State<PaymentHistoryScreen> {
  ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Setting up AppBar
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Payment History'),
      ),

      // Body
      body: Container(
        // your code here - you can use onpressed method in the body also.here I used it for floating button
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return new PaymentHistorySearchDialog(); //call the alert dart 
                }
            );
          },
          child: Container
            (
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.search_sharp, size: 32, color: Colors.white,)
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

**then code the alert dart as follows.**

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class PaymentHistorySearchDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return PaymentHistorySearchDialogState();
  }
}

class PaymentHistorySearchDialogState extends State<PaymentHistorySearchDialog> {

  String? selectedValue;
  List<String> items = [
    'All',
    'Completed',
    'Pending',
    'Rejected',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 5),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            bottom: 5
        ),
        title: Text(
            'Search'.toUpperCase(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 22,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontFamily: "medium",
            )
        ),
        content: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 220,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton2(
                  hint: Text(
                    'Select Status',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                  items: items
                      .map((item) =>
                      DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(
                          item,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                      .toList(),
                  value: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedValue = value as String;
                      //Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                    print(value);

                    // selectedValue = value as String;
                  },
                  buttonHeight: 30,
                  buttonWidth: double.infinity,
                  itemHeight: 40,
                  buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black38),
                    ),
                  ),
                  buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5),

                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  onTap: () {
          ///___________________________________________________________________
          // Get.defaultDialog(
          //   title: " وضعیت دزدگیر",
          //   middleText: "پیام اعلام وضعیت دزدگیر ارسال گردد؟",
          //   titleStyle: TextStyle(
          //       color: mainColor2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          //   middleTextStyle:
          //   TextStyle(color: mainColor6.withOpacity(0.9), fontSize: 15),
          // );
          ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
          // showDialog(
          //     context: context,
          //     builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          //       content: Column(
          //         children: <Widget>[
          //           TextField(
          //             decoration: InputDecoration(
          //               icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          //               labelText: 'Username',
          //             ),
          //           ),
          //           TextField(
          //             obscureText: true,
          //             decoration: InputDecoration(
          //               icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
          //               labelText: 'Password',
          //             ),
          //           ),
          //         ],
          //       ),
          //     ),
          // );
          ///___________________________________________________________________
          List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> listDrop = [];
          String selected=null;
          void loadData() {
            listDrop.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text("پایدار"),
              value:"555",
            ));
            listDrop.add(
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text("لحظه ای"),
                value:"444",
              ),
            );
          }
          loadData();

          Alert(
              context: context,
              title: "تنظیمات خروجی شماره ۱",
              // desc: ".",
              // image: Image.asset(
              //   "assets/settings.png",
              //   scale: 5,
              // ),
              content: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        controller: _codeShargController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'نام خروجی',
                          hintText: '${out1.read('codeShargController')}',
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                      Center(


                        child: DropdownButton(
                          underline: Container(
                            height: 1.5,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                          hint: Text("وضعیت عملکرد"),
                          items: listDrop,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: selected,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                          onChanged: (newValue)  {
                            selected = newValue;
                           // setState(() {});
                            setState(() { selected = newValue; });

                          },
                        ),





                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // content: Column(
              //   children: <Widget>[
              //
              //     SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              //
              //     TextField(
              //
              //       decoration: InputDecoration(
              //
              //         icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              //         labelText: 'Username',
              //       ),
              //     ),
              //     SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              //
              //     TextField(
              //       obscureText: true,
              //       decoration: InputDecoration(
              //         icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
              //         labelText: 'Password',
              //       ),
              //     ),
              //   ],
              // ),
              buttons: [
                DialogButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    out1.write(
                        "codeShargController", _codeShargController.text);

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "ثبت",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                )
              ]).show();

          ///___________________________________________________________________
```