# Flutter: Switch inside CupertinoActionSheet no updates state

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show a showCupertinoModalPopup in flutter which contains Switch, It is display correctly but does not update the Switch,. Why does the Switch not keeps the new state after update on a CupertinoActionSheet?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62264

```
  Future<int> countAsReturnVisit(CalendarEvent event) async {
        bool remember = false;
    
        var res = await showCupertinoModalPopup(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext cnt) {
            return Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: CupertinoActionSheet(
                message: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                        'Do you want to count \'Completed\' events as part of Return Visits?'
                            .i18n),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Remember this selection'.i18n),
                          Switch(
                            value: remember,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                remember = value;
                              });
                            },
                            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightBlue[200],
                            activeColor: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    child: Text('No'.i18n),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, 0);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                  isDefaultAction: true,
                  child: Text('Yes'.i18n),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, 1);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ) as int;
    
        if (res != null && res == 1) {
          setCalendarAlwaysCountAsRrtuVist();
        }
    
        return res;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

setState will only update current StatefulWidget's Widget Build function.

You should use StatefulBuilder.

For your case just add StatefulBuilder as a parent of your Switch widget, and use StateSetter when you want to update the StatefulBuilder's children.
It will only update the widget tree defined under StateFulBuilder builder function.

---

see this question answer: [63008037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008037/)

For more information on StatefulBuilder head over to [StateFulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) documentation page.