# Flutter-Web Progress Bar does not show upload progress

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I have written an upload function that uploads the selected files to Firebase Storage.

I can listen to the upload task and print the upload progress but I cannot somehow display it on a progress bar.

I even tried to display the progress as text on the alert dialogue but it always shows 0.00%

This is my upload Function:

```
uploadData() async {
  storageReference.putData(
   fileToUpload, SettabelMetaData(
                 contentType: 'image/*')
   ).snapshotEvents.listen((event) async {
       setState(() {
       _progress = event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / 
                   event.totalBytes.toDouble();
       });
       debugPrint(_progress.toString());
       showDialog(
           context: context,
           builder: (ctx) {
           return AlertDialog(
             backgroundColor: Colors.black,
             actions: [
             LinearProgressIndicator(
             value: _progress,
             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
             color: Colors.red.shade700,
             )
            ],
           title: Text(
                  'Uploading...',
                  style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  );
           });
        }
}
```

please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here, any suggestions will be of great help

Comment: you need your dialog to be `'stateful'` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-an-alertdialog-in-flutter

Comment: Understood let me try this out, thanks 

Comment: @griffins I tried the above solution it works but the issue is there are multiple alert dialogues been overlayed one over the other throughout the completion of the progress bar see this: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/pdmTF53.gifv).