# How to switch images in the list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a list with images. I receive several images, when I click on the image, the `_showImageDialog` method works for me and an image with buttons for scrolling is displayed (I attached a screenshot below). `station.photos![index]`. How can I switch to the next image when I click on the button? I tried to change the index but it didn't work for me why?

```
  void _showImageDialog(
      BuildContext context, PublicChargingStationModel station) {
    int index = 0;
    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        constants.Assets.closeBold,
                        color: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                        height: 26,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        constants.Assets.arrowLeft,
                        color: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                        height: 48,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                      child: station.photos!.isNotEmpty
                          ? CachedNetworkImage(
                              imageUrl: station.photos![index].url,
                              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                  Container(
                                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
                                height: 116,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
                                  height: 116,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(
                                Icons.error,
                                color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Image.asset(
                              constants.Assets.publicStation,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (index < station.photos!.length) {
                          setState(() {
                          index++;
                        });
                        station.photos![index].url;
                        } 
                      },
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        constants.Assets.arrowRight,
                        color: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                        height: 48,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also facing same issue in mobile development then i know we have to rebuild the whole dialog and then it will work well

[Reference for solve this same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73463389/18340828)

```html
int selectedRadio = 0; // Declare your variable outside the builder

return AlertDialog( 
  content: StatefulBuilder(  // You need this, notice the parameters below:
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Column(  // Then, the content of your dialog.
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
          return Radio<int>(
            value: index,
            groupValue: selectedRadio,
            onChanged: (int value) {
              // Whenever you need, call setState on your variable
              setState(() => selectedRadio = value);
            },
          );
        }),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to connect it to my code?

Comment: return AlertDialog( 
  content: StatefulBuilder(  // You need this, notice the parameters below:
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
  return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
}
}

Answer (score 1):

When you call setState then it call the build method and a dialog is not a part of this context.so the simple solution is **wrap your dialog with statefulbuilder widget and then you will get a setstate method for dialog. **

You can checkout this video for solution
https://www.google.com/search?q=setstate+in+dialog+johannes+milki&oq=setstate+in+dialog+johannes+milki&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l5.11920j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#

Comment: The first video of johannes milki.

Comment: I would be better if you could include some code-snippet that is related to the answer.  Check more about [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)