# State of the dialog not updating on dropdown change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dialog

So I have this function to show a reusable dialog that have a list of widget. The main problem lies in the dropdown and the text field. to begin with my dropdown value is A and I wanted the text field to only show when the dropdown value is B.

I tried some code already but when I choose the value B the text field won't show up, then if I close the dialog and try to open it again next time, that will show the text field that I want, but the value in the drop down is A not value B.

How can I achieve something like what I wanted ?

Here's my code :

```
  List<String> itemList = ["notMyExpertise", "Alasan lainnya"];
  String selectedReason = '';

  void rejectDialog(
      {required dynamic ticketData,
      required String ticketId,
      required VoidCallback onDeclineConfirmed}) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return ReusableConfirmationDialog(
            titleText: 'hello'.tr(),
            contentText: 'hello bro let me try to help you first before '.tr(),
            confirmButtonText: 'sure'.tr(),
            declineButtonText: 'cancel'.tr(),
            onDecline: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            onConfirm: onDeclineConfirmed,
            additionalWidget: Column(
              children: [
                ReusableDropdownButton(
                  itemList: itemList,
                  width: 197,
                  height: 26,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedReason = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                if (selectedReason == 'Alasan lainnya')
                  Container(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 78),
                    width: 230,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: othersChatColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: ticketTextController,
                      maxLength: 100,
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1000),
                      ],
                      style: primaryColor400Style.copyWith(
                        fontSize: fontSize11,
                      ),
                      maxLines: null,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'reasonHint'.tr(),
                        hintStyle: weight400Style.copyWith(
                            color: hintColor, fontSize: fontSize11),
                        counterText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: AlertDialog is tricky, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-an-alertdialog-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

Because the `dialog` and `bottom sheets` don't have states so you must create a different **stateful widget** for the widget you want to show in the `dialog` or `sheet` and then return it from the `dialog` or `bottom sheet`. that's how it will work as a `stateful widget` and will update as you want.

```
void rejectDialog(
      {required dynamic ticketData,
      required String ticketId,
      required VoidCallback onDeclineConfirmed}) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StateFulWidgetYouCreate();
          });
     }
```