# Functions do not work in the alert dialog

Tags: flutter, function

I want to do Alert dialog number increment (+1) number reduction (-1) number value reset (R), but it does not appear on the screen, when I save the file the value appears on the screen, how can I do this?
İmage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIQGT.png)

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: just see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-an-alertdialog-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `StateFull Widget` and `setState()`.
when you want to change value on screen dynamically call `setState()`
check the following example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

int currentValue = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

//use stateful widget when you want to change state
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          //show the current value on screen
          Text(
            '$currentValue',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),

          //button to show dialog
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("show Dialog "),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Dialog();
                  });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dialog({super.key});

  @override
  State<Dialog> createState() => _DialogState();
}

class _DialogState extends State<Dialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('$currentValue'),
      actions: [
        //button to increase the value of currentValue
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //call setState, it will Update the state
              setState(() {
                //increment the value
                currentValue++;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Increase')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                //reduce the value
                currentValue--;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Decrease')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                //reduce the value
                currentValue = 0;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Reset')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('Remove Dialog')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest. I write my functions in the atomic widget, I leave my codes below, I will be glad if you tell me where I made a mistake Code:

Comment: Number increase and decrease functions : int yolcuSayisi = 0;
  
  void yolcuArtiBir() {
    setState(() {
      yolcuSayisi++;
    });
  }

  void yolcuEksiBir() {
    setState(() {
      yolcuSayisi--;
    });
  }

Comment: can you put your whole code in your question?

Comment: IconButton(
                            color: Colors.green.shade600,
                            iconSize: 30,
                            onPressed: () {
                              yolcuArtiBir();
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one)),
                        IconButton(
                            iconSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            onPressed: () {
                              yolcuEksiBir();

Comment: there is no problem with your functions, to show updated value in `dialog` create a separate `Stateful Widget` for Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Please make your class `StatelessWidget` to `StatefullWidget` and use `setState` while calling `onPressed()`

```
onPressed: () { 
     setState(() { 
             //logic
     }); 
}
```

Hope this helps!